# Immutability - Java, Final required if no setters

Tags: java, immutability

I have already read that for `Immutable object` , what are the initial requirements to create it.

But i am not clear about

If we do not expose our `field setters, should we still make the fields final`, if yes why..??

Comment: I f you want to make your Object immutable, why have setters at all? the ctor accepts field values ant that's it

Comment: if you dont want your variable to be modified, make it final, and in that case you dont need setter anyway